# Read Encrypted Passwords from SQL Server table with C#

Tags: sql, passwords, encryption

I am trying to read a Username and a Password from a table in SQL Server, via a C# code module;  The password field in the table is purposely encrypted, and the following error is received:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'v/InaNkI2CLaJHg5urBWCw=='.

The Select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
from dbo.MembershipFA 
Where UserName = 'xxx' and 'v/InaNkI2CLaJHg5urBWCw=='
```

Any insight is appreciated;  Best regards - Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a syntax error. It should be somehting like

```
SELECT * from dbo.MembershipFA Where UserName = 'xxx' and Password = 'v/InaNkI2CLaJHg5urBWCw=='
```

Answer (score 1):

you're missing part of the query. which column are you comparing to? Probably a column called `Password` I'd guess

```
SELECT * 
from dbo.MembershipFA 
Where UserName = 'xxx' and **Password =** 'v/InaNkI2CLaJHg5urBWCw=='
```